# JQuery Javascript background colour change/highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can you do a simple table row change bg colour for x seconds then change back in pure Javascript or JQuery?

What I've tried doesn't seem to work, and I'd rather avoid the use of any further plugins seeing as I've done everything else in JQuery or Javascript alone.

What I'm after is a flash/ short highlight effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headshota's method will work. here is an alternative way.

```
$('#yourelementid').addClass('backgroundClass').delay(5000).queue(function(){$('#yourelementid').removeClass('backgroundClass');});
```

And then define a CSS class

```
.backgroundClass { background:blue;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzJ7P/9/)**

Comment: I like this, but the second time round it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr.yourRow').css({'background-color': 'red'});

setTimeout(function(){
   $('tr.yourRow').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
}, 6000);
```